# Open with Explorer is greyed out -SharePoint 2013

Tags: open-with-explorer

In a collaboration site , when admin of the collaboration adds an external user with full control , Open with Explorer option is greyed out for the external user .Please can you suggest solution ?
I have already added site to trusted sites , compatibility view , external user is using IE11(32 bit).

Comment: I think SP does this with WebDAV...probably webDAV cannot get out to your external user...

Comment: I can not understand can you please elaborate ?

Comment: WebDAV is the protocol used by "Net use" and his friends...Open with Explorer uses this (I think) so normally this cannot go thru a firewall to external users...ask the network guy about the webDAV protocol